# Displaying a image in a div

Tags: asp.net, css

I am having problems to display a image in a div element.

In the div is a custom web control (a login control).

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" Theme="Styles" %>
<%@ Register src="wucLogin.ascx" tagname="wucLogin" tagprefix="log" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="App_Themes/Styles/LoginStyleSheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="divLogin">

        <log:wucLogin id="WebUserControlLogin" runat="server" />         
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything gets displayed as it should. A basic login control with some basic layout and a blue background.

But when i try to put a picture in the div i cannot get it to display. I tried every possible path for the image so i do not think i have made a error there.

Basicly i want the login control to display, with behind it a picture (centered).

Css for the div element (the map images is directly a map in the root:

```
#divLogin
{
    background-image: url('../Images/test2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;

    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;

    top: 40%;
    left: 52.8%;
    width: 401px;
    height: 123px;
    margin-top: -61,5px;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Make sure that the image path is relative to the css file and not the aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see an ID of "divLog" on your page .. just "divLogin" .. could that be the issue?

Comment: That was a typ when pasting the code in here, its propertly named in my code.

Answer (score 0):

change position to relative, and put the login stuff inside the image div. also update the top and left for the relative positioning.

just a thought.